# Nginx proxy to Go dramatically reduces performance

Tags: nginx, proxy, configuration

I just finished coding up a small Go script listening with the Go http package. I wanted to put nginx in front of it (I need to serve static files in a subdir as well), but noticed that req/sec and latency fell dramatically (from 11K req/sec to 1.5K req/sec).

Is there anything wrong with my nginx config? (I'm testing on Mac by the way if that makes a difference)

```
worker_processes  4;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip  on;

    include sites/*.conf;
}
```

And my server config:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  go.dev;

    charset utf-8;
    root   /www;

    location /favicon.ico { return 404; }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }
}
```

Comment: How many concurrent requests are you doing?  Might be bottlenecking on worker processes.

Comment: @ShaneMadden I'm benchmarking on 250 requests. But why would nginx's performance at this load be worse than Go's?

Comment: Do you mean 250 concurrent requests?

Comment: Yep, 250 concurrent requests for 10 seconds.

Comment: If you turn the concurrency down to, say, 10, are the results much closer together?

Comment: No, even at 10 concurrent requests it's 23K vs 1.2K

Comment: Hmm.  How about if you use an `upstream` with something like `keepalive 64;`?  Also, as a test, see how many reqs/second your nginx serves when just requesting a tiny file that doesn't get proxied to Go?

Comment: Yeah, tried both of those, the result with `upstream` and `keepalive` was the same, Nginx can serve a small file at over 25K.

Comment: Ok, then the bottleneck's almost certainly in the proxying - can you try having Go listen for HTTP on a unix socket and point nginx at that so it's not going through the work of dealing with TCP?

Comment: @ShaneMadden That increased it to ~7K req/sec! It's still a bit less than plain Go, but it's probably just the nginx proxy overhead. I'll also look into serving static files from within Go as well (though it won't be as fast as nginx)

Comment: Have you seen http://serverfault.com/a/422850/211028 ?

Comment: @AlexeyTen Thanks for the link, I'll look into it (but I think I've already tried `multi_accept`).